# Identify where a line is being generated in Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

**TLDR:** How can I identify what's being added by the call to `<jdoc:include type="head" />`?

In an attempt to avoid doing yet another site for friends/family, this time I set up a copy of Joomla 3 on AWS, handed over the creds and thought "Job well done"... More fool me.

*Somehow* Joomla has been configured in a way that's throwing a JS Exception. Specifically, something's attempting to call jQuery and getting an undefined error. Note that there's a call to `jQuery.noConflict();` *after* the line with the error.

Needless to say, the person in question doesn't really know what they've done because they were following a guide to add a contact form that they can no longer find.

Words have been had. **Emphatically**.

How can I track down which plugin/extension/template added a particular line in the output?

The offending script is being dumped directly into the main page, not linked and is semi-minified.

I'm hoping that the fact that it comes after the external script files, just before what looks like a session keep-alive Ajax request will be a good enough pointer.

The beautified version of the script looks something like this...

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    new JCaption('img.caption');
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({
        "html": true,
        "container": "body"
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hasPopover').popover({
        "html": true,
        "trigger": "hover focus",
        "container": "body"
    });
});
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            /* Lots of validation rules */
        },
        highlight: function(label) {
            $(label).closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass("valid").closest(".control-group").addClass("success");
        }
    });
});

window.setInterval(function() {
    var r;
    try {
        r = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    } catch (e) {}
    if (r) {
        r.open("GET", "./", true);
        r.send(null)
    }
}, 840000);
```

It looks like it's trying to validate a contact form so is a likely culprit but there isn't one on the site (at least, not one that's working/visible).

Just after that block is a non-jQuery Ajax request to the home page (every 14 minutes?) I assume this is some form of session keep-alive. Ironically this doesn't rely on jQuery.

I've looked at the template's `component.php` and that whole section seems to be added via a `<jdoc:include type="head" />`

What's the next link in the chain? I can't see any files or xml blocks that specify what the `head` include relates to.

Comment: if you post the url I can give you more hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the error:**

You can read the reason why the javascript is not working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554537/joomla-3-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-anonymous-function).

So in there you'll find the fix.

**About how to find the file:**

Just search for  `$("#contact-form")` in the following folders:

```
components/
modules/
templates
```

There is hight canches the it's a module so maybe it could be useful for your investigation that you track if this error is in each page or just in some pages.

If it's in all the pages probably the file is in the `templates` or component folder otherwise it's a module.

If it's a module you just have to go in the backend and check the module enabled in the page broken.

I hope it's gonna be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'd already tracked down the _why_ but not the _where_. A `grep -R` found the files I needed and I tracked it back to the appropriate module. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah grep is always amazing :)